# How can I communicate whether side effects have been successful or not?

Tags: rust, error-handling, side-effects

With the Rust project I am working on I would like to keep the code as clean as I can but was having issues with side effects - more specifically how to communicate whether they have been successful or not. Assume we have this enum and struct (the struct may contain more members not relevant to my question):

```rust
enum Value{
    Mutable(i32),
    Constant(i32),
}

struct SomeStruct {
    // --snip--
    value: Value
}
```

I would like to have a function to change `value`:

```rust
impl SomeStruct {
    fn change_value(&mut self, new_value: i32) {
        match self.value {
            Value::Mutable(_) => self.value = Value::Mutable(new_value),
            Value::Constant(_) => (), /* meeeep! do not do this :( */
        }
    }
}
```

I am now unsure how to cleanly handle the case where `value` is `Value::Constant`.

From what I've learned in C or C++ you would just return a `bool` and return `true` when `value` was successfully changed or `false` when it wasn't. This does not feel satisfying as the function signature alone would not make it clear what the `bool` was for. Also, it would make it optional for the caller of `change_value` to just ignore the return value and not handle the case where the side effect did not actually happen. I could, of course, adjust the function name to something like `try_changing_value` but that feels more like a band-aid than actually fixing the issue.

The only alternative I know would be to approach it more "functionally":

```rust
fn change_value(some_struct: SomeStruct, new_value: i32) -> Option<SomeStruct> {
    match self.value {
        Value::Mutable(_) => {
            let mut new_struct = /* copy other members */;
            new_struct.value = Value::Mutable(new_value);
            Some(new_struct)
        },
        Value::Constant(_) => None,
    }
}
```

However, I imagine if `SomeStruct` is expensive to copy this is not very efficient. **Is there another way to do this?**

Finally, to give some more context as to how I got here: My actual code is about solving a sudoku and I modelled a sudoku's cell as either having a given (`Value::Constant`) value or a guessed (`Value::Mutable`) value. The "given" values are the once you get at the start of the puzzle and the "guessed" values are the once you fill in yourself. This means changing "given" values should not be allowed. If modelling it this way is the actual issue, I would love to hear your suggestions on how to do it differently!

Comment: Thank you very much! Both suggestions are not something I considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general pattern to indicate whether something was successful or not is to use `Result`:

```
struct CannotChangeValue;

impl SomeStruct {
    fn change_value(&mut self, new_value: i32) -> Result<(), CannotChangeValue> {
        match self.value {
            Value::Mutable(_) => {
                self.value = Value::Mutable(new_value);
                Ok(())
            }
            Value::Constant(_) => Err(CannotChangeValue),
        }
    }
}
```

That way the caller can use the existing methods, syntax, and other patterns to decide how to deal with it. Like ignore it, log it, propagate it, do something else, etc. And the compiler will warn that the caller will need to do *something* with the result (even if that something is to explicitly ignore it).

---

If the API is designed to let callers determine exactly how to mutate the value, then you may want to return `Option<&mut i32>` instead to indicate: *"I may or may not have a value that you can mutate, here it is."* This also has a wealth of methods and tools available to handle it.

I think that `Result` fits your use-case better, but it just depends on the  flexibility and level of abstraction that you're after.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is probably what I want. The two things that bother me about it, is that the handling of the error is not as mandatory as using an `Option` (where unwrapping could panic) and that there is no relevant `Ok` value. But I guess that is as close to clean as I can get. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness with kmdreko's answer, this is the way you would implement a mut-ref-getter, which IMO is the simpler and more flexible approach:

```
enum Value {
    Mutable(i32),
    Constant(i32),
}

impl Value {
    pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut i32> {
        match self {
            Value::Mutable(ref mut v) => Some(v),
            Value::Constant(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike the `Result` approach, this *forces* the caller to consider that setting the value may not be possible.  (Granted, `Result` is a `must_use` type, so they'd get a warning if discarding it.)

You can write a proxy method on `SomeStruct` that forwards the invocation to this method:

```
impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn get_mut_value(&mut self) -> Option<&mut i32> {
        self.value.get_mut()
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need `ref mut`. `self` is already a mutable reference, so the matched bindings will already be mutable references due to match ergonomics.

Comment: @kmdreko I know. I think it makes the code more clear. The minimum possible amount of code is not always the most readable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!
Exposing the value as a `&mut i32` is probably a good choice. Now that I think about it... It does kind of go against my effort of encapsulating it as much as possible. The user could write anything they want into the i32, which I could prevent using `Result`. But then again, that does not make the handling of the error as mandatory and it is kind of weird having no relevant `Ok` value. But again, thank you very much for the input :)